# Why does ShowDialogue() fire Close() when setting Visible = false in Show()?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I set Visible = false in the show event of a Form shown with ShowDialogue() the form will automatically call it's close event.  I don't want to close the form...just hide it.  So I have to call Show() instead.  But, this doesn't block.

Why does setting Visible = false causes form close to fire with ShowDialogue()?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Hiding a modal dialog and expecting pass active input back to the caller sounds like working against the system in place. Instead of hiding the modal dialog consider using it as a modal and passing a state object around as needed if you need to show it again. FWIW hiding a modal dialog calls close because if you were able to hide a modal dialog and not close it, the user would have to end the process of your application because the modal would still be maintaining sole focus.

Comment: Just think it through a bit.  ShowDialog() disables all other windows in the app.  You hide the one and only window that the user can focus.  How does the user ever get back to the app?

Comment: Does showdialogUE really work?

Comment: @HansPassant - Its funny...a lot of these issues I've been experiencing boil down to a root problem.  Not checking `Control.IsInvokeRequired` and acting accordingly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to fire `Show()`, instead of `ShowDialogue()`, if it don't work you can try to use `Hide()` or modify the `Opacity` property.